# VBA: Combine and move to new sheet

Tags: vba, copy, move, paste

Using VBA, how can I solve the following:

I need to combine `column A` (`row 1,2,3,...,lastrow`) & and `column B` (`row a,b,c`) from `sheet1` into `column A` and `Column B` on `sheet2` as follows:

```
1 a

1 b

1 c

2 a

2 b

2 c

3 a

3 b

3 c

...

lastrow a

lastrow b

lastrow c
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Are you looking to create a macro?  If so what code have you tried?

Comment: I am quite new to this, so all i managed so far was to copy column A from sheet1 to sheet2

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a macro that does what you want.  More on running a macro here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/run-a-macro-HP010342865.aspx

```
Sub CopyExtra()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim CurRow As Long
Dim DestRow As Long

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = 1 To LastRow
    DestRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A" & DestRow & ":A" & DestRow + 2).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & CurRow).Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B3").Copy
        .Range("B" & DestRow & ":B" & DestRow + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
Next CurRow
End Sub
```